# How a client(web browser) use public key on CA certificate to authenticate digital signature on server certificate?

Tags: security, ssl, https, certificate, digital-signature

While studying how https works, ssl handshake in https, following points were raised without getting complete answer.
In the flow of https, how client upon receiving server certificate validates its authenticity using digital signature in server certificate and public key of CA certificate.

May anyone explain this in brief?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In brief the idea of asymmetric cryptography is that you can encrypt with one key and decrypt with another key. The idea of digital signature is that you can encrypt with private key and decrypt with public key.

So when CA issues certificate for server it encodes some fields of certificate (described in [specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3280.txt)):

```
   TBSCertificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
        version         [0]  EXPLICIT Version DEFAULT v1,
        serialNumber         CertificateSerialNumber,
        signature            AlgorithmIdentifier,
        issuer               Name,
        validity             Validity,
        subject              Name,
        subjectPublicKeyInfo SubjectPublicKeyInfo,
        issuerUniqueID  [1]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                             -- If present, version MUST be v2 or v3
        subjectUniqueID [2]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                             -- If present, version MUST be v2 or v3
        extensions      [3]  EXPLICIT Extensions OPTIONAL
                             -- If present, version MUST be v3
        }
```

in DER format and then encrypts it with its private key using `signatureAlgorithm`. When browser receives server certificate it takes the same fields in DER format  then it takes CA public key and decrypts the encrypted signature of certificate using `signatureAlgorithm`.

If they match, that means that the certificate was really signed by CA and it can be trusted.